# textfield Validation in blackberry java

Tags: blackberry, eclipse-plugin, java-me

i am validating a password field where it has to contain atleast one capital letter and one number.i used below code but its not working?

```
for (int i = 0;i<Password.getText().length(); i++) {

        char i1 = Password.getText().charAt(i);
        boolean valid;
    if ( valid=(i1!='A'||i1!='B'||i1!='C'||i1!='D'||i1!='E'||i1!='F'||i1!='G'||i1!='H'||i1!='I'||i1!='J'||i1!='K'||i1!='L'||i1!='M'||i1!='N'||i1!='O'||i1!='P'||i1!='Q'||i1!='R'||i1!='S'||i1!='T'||i1!='U'||i1!='V'||i1!='W'||i1!='X'||i1!='Y'||i1!='Z')&&(i1!='1'||i1!='2'||i1!='3'||i1!='4'||i1!='5'||i1!='6'||i1!='7'||i1!='8'||i1!='9'||i1!='0')) {

        if(valid=true){
                return true;
            }else{
            return false;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why do you use no regular expression?

Comment: @Michael Dorner could we use regular expression in javaMe using blackberry eclipse plugin?if it so when i googled i was informed to import package using import me.regexp.*; but it shows error and tells to remove unused import.

Comment: There isn't regex support, but you can use [regex-me](https://code.google.com/p/regexp-me/). Judging from your comment, you've tried this. I have used this lib and know it works. So it might be an issue with importing the lib. I know I had to import as a preverified Jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your password must have at least one capital letter and at least one number your logic is wrong. You should have two booleans.

```
boolean hasCapitalLetter = false;
boolean hasNumber = false;

for (int i = 0;i<Password.getText().length(); i++) {
    char i1 = Password.getText().charAt(i);

    if (!hasCapitalLetter) {
        hasCapitalLetter = Character.isUpperCase(i1);
    }
    if (!hasNumber) {
        hasNumber = Character.isDigit(i1);
    }
    if (hasCapitalLetter && hasNumber) {
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
```